# UIWebViewで表示される画像を、カメラロールにそのまま保存したい

Tags: ios, objective-c

UIWebViewで表示される画像を、カメラロールに保存したいと考えています。
表示している画像URL、オリジナルの画像そのものをダウンロードできるものでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWebViewの画面表示内容をイメージにしたいのであれば
renderInContextを使えばよいです。
(参考)
http://blog.syuhari.jp/archives/2145

画像が格納されているURLからオリジナルイメージを
取得したいのであれば、initWithContentsOfURLで
ダウンロードしたNSDataをimageWithDataでUIImageに
変換すればよいです。
(参考)
http://www.yoheim.net/blog.php?q=20130104

UIImageをカメラロールに保存したいなら
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbumを使えばよいです。
(参考)
http://obc-fight.blogspot.jp/2013/01/uiimage-saved-in-photolibrary.html